# Select latest row value for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Please take a look at the below sql fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26b91/1

[Latest SQL Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e79/2)

I will try to describe the output I require first.  I am expecting two rows since there are two conditions in the `PullPointDate` table.  The multiple rows that are in the `PullPoint` table are there due to audit data, the audit values start from 1 to 3 for condition 1 and from 1 to 2 for condition 2.  As you can see it is possible for there to be many audits of the data.  Other columns in the full data set are obviously changing however I have not included them here as they are not relevant.  Needless to say it is possible for their to be (n) conditions and associated pullpoint audit change data.

Columns

```
CondNumber,  StudyCode,  PullPeriod, PullUnit
1         ,   SS3105  ,   52       , Weeks
2         ,   SS3105  ,   24       , Weeks
```

The other rows in the `PullPoint` table should not feature in the results as they have older i.e less `AuditNumber` than the latest `AuditNumber`.

I have struggled with this for quite some time.  My mind struggles to think in a set based fashion.  Nested Row_Over, Partition By etc has me breaking out in cold sweats.

How do I achieve this the closest I could get was one row looking perfect yet the other value was null owing to me doing a where clause on the audit number and owing to the two conditions being different only one rows details were returned.

Thank you

Any more information I will try to provide.

Comment: I put the link to the latest fiddle from the comments into the question and changed tags of the question, because the question is related to SQL query, not to the SQL Fiddle tool. Please edit the expected result in the question to match the latest fiddle sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Vladimir Baranov's answer you can also use the CTE with Row_Number:
[SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e79/19/0)

```
WITH CTE 
AS 
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY  
         P.BatchCode ORDER BY P.AuditNumber Desc) RN ,
         P.StudyCode , P.BatchCode ,  
         PP.condNumber ,P.pullunit , P.PullPeriod
          FROM pullpoint P
          JOIN PullPointDate PP
          ON P.BatchCode = PP.BatchCode 

 )

  SELECT  StudyCode , 
          BatchCode ,  
          condNumber ,
          pullunit , 
          PullPeriod
 FROM CTE
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
select distinct condNumber, pp.studycode, pullperiod, pullunit 
from PullPoint pp
join PullPointDate ppd on ppd.studycode = pp.StudyCode
and pp.batchCode = ppd.batchcode
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26b91/5)

Comment: I hope to ****** its not that simple, I am sure there must be more data at play in my table structure.  I have added some more data to one of the tables and more results are now pouring out more like what they were doing at work.  I am sorry the original question was lacking some data.  My bad.  I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: I don't think your additional data is showing in the same fiddle.  I think the fiddle link gets changed when you update it, so could you post the updated fiddle link?

Comment: Hey sorry buddy, Could you please take another look for me. I think i was editing your public fiddle.  Again sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to give me what I desire...

SELECT o.*
FROM pullpoint o
  LEFT JOIN pullpoint b
      ON o.studyCode = b.studyCode
      and o.batchCode = b.batchcode
       AND o.auditNumber < b.AuditNumber
WHERE b.AuditNumber is NULL

I am sure I will get to work tomorrow and the thing will not work though :(

Answer (score 0):

For each `BatchCode` from `PullPointDate` we look for one row from `PullPoint` that has the largest `AuditNumber` using `CROSS APPLY`. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e79/10/0). I used your http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e79/2 as a source of sample data.

It is not clear whether you need to join two tables on `StudyCode` as well. If it is necessary, just add `AND PullPoint.StudyCode = CTE.StudyCode` to the `WHERE` condition.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
  SELECT StudyCode, BatchCode, CondNumber
  FROM PullPointDate
  GROUP BY StudyCode, BatchCode, CondNumber
)
SELECT * 
FROM
  CTE
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP(1) PullPoint.PullUnit, PullPoint.PullPeriod
    FROM PullPoint
    WHERE PullPoint.BatchCode = CTE.BatchCode
    ORDER BY PullPoint.AuditNumber DESC
  ) AS CA
;
```